# Google static maps via iPhone connected to AT&T wireless network not working

Tags: iphone, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Recently I've been having issues retrieving static maps on my iPhone when connected to the AT&T wireless network. But, when I connect to a local WiFi is works fine.

For several hours last Sunday is stopped working and then it started to work for the rest of the evening, then today I see that it has stopped working again.

I'm just using the safari browser to test that I can download the static map, it returns the quota has been exceeded image. But, there is no way I've exceeded the quota.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.703049,-74.010695&zoom=16&format=jpg&sensor=false&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap

Is anyone else having the same issue? I've reproduced the issue with several other apple devices that are connected the the AT&T wireless network.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check what tags relate to before you use them, 'att' doesn't refer to the AT&T phone network!

Comment: In fact, is this a programming question, or do you mean that the Maps app isn't working?

Comment: @adamjansch: Hadn't noticed that. Edited for OP.

Comment: It was a http call to a the goggle static maps question, no programing is necessary.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, it sounds like this question might be more relevant at one of the other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 6):

This is [a known problem](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/88e5702fd8528ba0/). It's caused by mobile providers routing all internet requests through a few static IP addresses. Handsets are terminals within their own internal network (and generally have a 10.n.n.n IP address), and all traffic is routed through external-facing proxy servers.

There is no way around it other than

- persuade Google to whitelist AT&T's proxy servers
- persuade AT&T to use more proxy servers
- vote with your feet to use a service provider which has more proxy servers

Comment: I signed up for a google key via the Google APIs console and tried to put the key into the http call. However, this did not help.

Comment: Is there a way to route the http call so google sees a different ip address? The only solution I can imagine at the moment would be to build a server outside of the mobile provider network that can make the call for me and return the result.

Comment: I solved this issue by adding a google API key, remember to make sure that the google api key is granted permissions for Google Static Maps.