# 403 Forbidden in Google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

As it is stated that Api key is not needed in Google maps v3 but using`http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false` I was only able to use maps for 3 days then I started getting 403 Forbidden error. I only send about 300-400 requests per day so that shouldnt have been a problem.

Then, I decided to get the api key and used it, it also worked fine for 3 days; after that it generated same 403 forbidden error.

Can anyone please guide me if I am missing something or getting business plan for google api is the only way?

Thanks

Comment: As @jlivni says, check your usage in the Console. Are you on shared hosting, or using a mobile network? If so, [this might be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420327/google-static-maps-via-iphone-connected-to-att-wireless-network-not-working/10420712#10420712). Or, Google may have detected a breach of their Terms. Too many potential reasons to speculate, really.

Comment: Your problem may be js caching of old api js. Check out this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719319/after-months-of-100-stability-today-i-get-403-error-on-google-maps-services

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a key, although it is recommended (amongst other things, it will allow you to see your usage in the API console).

Do you have a link to your site so we can see if there's potentially another reason the 403's are occurring?